# R ggplot won't show legend colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I'm trying to make a plot with geom_linerange(), with aes(color) given by a variable.

I don't understand why it doesn't show colors in legends' box.
[image]

Here's my plot code:

```
estancias_uci %>% 
  arrange(desc(box),desc(first_cauris)) %>% 
  rowid_to_column("patient_id") %>% 
  ggplot(data=.,
         aes(x=nhc)) +
  geom_linerange(
    aes(ymin=first_cauris-hours(6),ymax=last_cauris+hours(6)),
    colour="grey",
    size=4,alpha=0.5) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=from,ymax=to,color=box), size=2, alpha=0.9)  + 
  coord_flip() + 
  xlab("") + 
  ggtitle("UCI 2021") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        legend.title.align = 0.5)
```

Thanks

***Reproducible Code***

```
estancias_uci <- structure(list(nhc = c(1057591, 1867803, 1867803, 231669, 231669, 
    231669, 2829584, 2829584, 2877093, 2877093, 2877093, 2935589, 
    2935589, 3078408, 3188088, 3188088, 3193727, 3193727, 3193727, 
    6080761, 6787731, 6787731, 6787731), from = structure(c(1610125680, 
    1611092580, 1615554240, 1611701220, 1614024120, 1616442960, 1612849620, 
    1614024120, 1610797440, 1610797620, 1614249780, 1615318260, 1616508540, 
    1614952440, 1615236240, 1615395120, 1610057340, 1612637100, 1614171300, 
    1612305960, 1613691540, 1614372060, 1620653340), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), to = structure(c(1616187780, 1615554240, 1617456120, 
    1614024120, 1616442960, 1617471240, 1614024120, 1615053600, 1610797620, 
    1614249780, 1614622320, 1616508540, 1621436460, 1616434140, 1615395120, 
    1615817940, 1612637100, 1614171300, 1616434560, 1613989800, 1614372060, 
    1620653340, 1622131020), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), box = c("BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", 
    "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", 
    "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-3", "BOX-3", "BOX-1", 
    "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1", "BOX-1"), first_cauris = structure(c(1613347200, 
    1615161600, 1615161600, 1613606400, 1613606400, 1613606400, 1613606400, 
    1613606400, 1614211200, 1614211200, 1614211200, 1617667200, 1617667200, 
    1616371200, 1615766400, 1615766400, 1615161600, 1615161600, 1615161600, 
    1612742400, 1613952000, 1613952000, 1613952000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), last_cauris = structure(c(1615939200, 1618012800, 
    1618012800, 1617667200, 1617667200, 1617667200, 1614816000, 1614816000, 
    1615161600, 1615161600, 1615161600, 1618444800, 1618444800, 1617062400, 
    1616976000, 1616976000, 1618272000, 1618272000, 1618272000, 1613606400, 
    1618444800, 1618444800, 1618444800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Would you give us `cauris_covid_clz` ?

Comment: I've already updated it, both code and reproducible dataset, now `estancias_uci` is already joined. I forgot I had joined it with `cauris_covid_clz`.

Comment: I ran your sample data and example code in my RStudio session and the colors appeared in the legend box. // Does this simplified example work `ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width)) + geom_linerange(aes(ymin=1,ymax=4,color=Species), size=2, alpha=0.9) `

Comment: I restarted my session. When I zoom the plot I can see the labels' colors, but I cannot in the plot viewer. Is there any parameter to set the square legends' width? Or is it a bug?

Comment: Could be a bug. What versions of ggplot2 are you running? (I tested in R version 4.0.4, ggplot2 version 3.3.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be you are setting the alpha for those colors but you don't want to use alpha in the legend. Try adding

```
 guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1)))
```

to your plot. That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me too.